# send value from php file to js file

Tags: javascript, php

i want pass value from php to js file , code like this
but not working
what wrong ?

thanks

php file

```
$var = 10;
<script>
var phpVar = "<?php echo json_encode($var) ?>;";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='vendor/circliful/circliful.custom.js'></script>
```

js file

```
$("#overallProgress").circliful({
        animationStep: 5,
        foregroundBorderWidth: 12,
        backgroundBorderWidth: 6,
        percent: 'alert(phpVar);', **<-- place value from php**
        fontColor: '#000000',
        foregroundColor: '#1a8e5f',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
//      icon: '\eab4',
        iconColor: '#1a8e5f',
        iconPosition: 'middle',
//      text: 'Statistik',
        textBelow: true,
        animation: 1,
        animationStep: 1,
        start: 2,
        showPercent: 1,     
    });
```

sorry all i have mistake code in php
this right code

```
<?php
$var = 67;
?>
<script>
var phpVar = <?php echo json_encode($var) ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='vendor/circliful/circliful.custom.js'></script>
```

Comment: try removing the semicolon after the `<?php echo json_encode($var) ?>;`

Comment: Try removing the quotes, too. `json_encode` should produce valid JavaScript. Also *inspect the output* source to be sure it looks correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: @Juakali92  var phpVar = <?php echo json_encode($var) ?>; not working

Comment: @MimoudiX already read..but not same situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alert is a javascript function which display a message box, also you can't wrap it in a single quote, just add phpvar variable and test

```
percent: phpVar,
```

Comment: percent: phpVar,
not working

Comment: is there any javascript errors in console?try to log the value of phpVar before that function 
`console.log(phpVar);
$("#overallProgress").circliful({
`

Comment: my site show white screen...no log

Comment: if you're using googe chrome browser press ctrl + shift + i and check for any errors in the console tab

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
this theme complex , if make false value get white screen

​if  percent: '10', error disappeared

Comment: I think you need to review the code on server side first, it seems like you have an error on the back-end

Comment: check my question already edit...this my mistake coding in php file.....thank for your time